# CDK AWS Lambda how to mock the asset provided

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, ts-jest

I am using `jest` for testing and I have a lambda function in my Stack I want to test.
Like this:

```
const lambda = new lambda.Function(this, "MyLambda", {
   ...
   code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("../assets/lambda.zip"),
   ...
   }
);
```

I want to test some of the properties but also if the lambda is in the stack. But when I run the test it complains that my `lambda.zip` doesn't exist. Which is fair enough, as it's built as part of the another build job.
Is there any way to inject or somehow mock the lambda's asset.

Comment: I'd create an empty file and delete it afterwards. Not sure if that's the optimal way, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Code.fromInline()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Code.html#static-fromwbrinlinecode) as it doesn't require any files on disk. Simply pass a dummy function code as a string.

```
lambda.Code.fromInline("exports.handler = async function(event, context) {}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [kichik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70469510/17791257)'s idea to use `Code.fromInline()`, this worked for me:

```
import { InlineCode } from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda"

jest.mock("@aws-cdk/aws-lambda", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("@aws-cdk/aws-lambda"),
  Code: {
    fromAsset: () => new InlineCode("foo"),
  },
}))
```

Probably can be simplified with `jest.spyOn`, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of simple scenarios, there's no need to bother with a complicated jest mocking.

```js
beforeAll(() => {
  Object.defineProperty(Code, 'fromAsset', {
    value: () => Code.fromInline('test code'),
  });
});
```